# Cheap way to move appartment contents from Estonia to Ireland (no urgency)

Tags: relocation, ireland, estonia

What's the cheapest way to move a lot of stuff. TV's, Desktop computers, Furniture etc. From Estonia to Ireland. I don't care if it takes a couple of months even if it's cheap.

There are some services advertising at the moment on facebook but the price is ridiculousness, more than ryanair baggage prices.

Comment: Are you relocating, or have you already relocated?

Comment: I'm asking only in theory for now. But for the purposes of this question I'm relocating.

Answer (score 1):

Driving yourself (via. some of the ferries), or sending standard sized moving boxes by regular freight mail.

The relocation ("removal") companies like Crown and Alpha can also do this for you, but for the amount you're talking about it's easily 3-5000 EUR.